# Regex match if found

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've the below 2 statements

```
<p class="chapterHeadA" id="cha35" style="text-indent: 0%;">
<p class="chapterHeadA" id="cha36">
```

I want to match both, i.e. if I have `style="text-indent: 0%;"`, match it else ignore this and match the rest(as in second statement)

I'm trying the below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<p class=\"(.*)\" id=\"(.*)\" (style=\"text-indent: (.*)%;)?\">
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how Can I match this.

Also I've something else like

```
<p class="chapterHeadA" id="cha15" style="text-indent: 0%;"><span class="bold">
<p class="chapterHeadA" id="cha15" style="text-indent: 0%;">1. <span class="bold">
```

When I apply my regex, the match is caught till the end of `=bold>`, is there a way that I can restrict it to catch only till `>` of `p class` tag

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the space and the last double quote in the `(...)?`, since they are not present in your second string.

```
<p class=\"(.*)\" id=\"(.*)\"( style=\"text-indent: (.*)%;\")?>
```

As for your updated question, make the regex in quotes lazy, so as it matches the minimal amount of text possible.

```
<p class=\"(.*?)\" id=\"(.*?)\"( style=\"text-indent: (.*?)%;\")?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use :

```
/<p.* style="text-indent: 0%;">/gm
```

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/wT7kM8/1)